# Kendo Ui Treeview select only one parent node at a time

Tags: jquery-ui, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-treeview

I am working on Kendo UI Treeview. Currently i have an requirement like When a parent node  are respected child node get selected and other parent nodes and their respected child nodes should be disabled(My kendo treeview contains many parents and children nodes).

Edit: Code Added

```
 @(Html.Kendo().TreeView()
       .Name("Countries")
       .DataTextField("CityName")
       .Events(e => {
          e.Check("getSelecedFacilities");
          e.DataBound("onDataBound");
      })
      .Checkboxes(checkboxes => checkboxes
           .Name("cityCheck")
           .CheckChildren(true)
       )
       .BindTo((IEnumerable<CountryModel>)ViewBag.Country, (Kendo.Mvc.UI.Fluent.NavigationBindingFactory<TreeViewItem> mappings) =>
       {
           mappings.For<CityModel>(binding => binding.ItemDataBound((item, parent) =>
           {
               item.Id = parent.Id.ToString();
               item.Text = parent.Name;
               item.HtmlAttributes.Add("class", "citycheck");
           })
           .Children(p => p.City));
           mappings.For<CityModel>(binding => binding.ItemDataBound((item, child) =>
           {
               item.Id = child.Code;
               item.Text = child.Name;
               item.HtmlAttributes.Add("class", "citycheck");
           }));
       })
 )
```

Script i Used:

```
             function onDataBound() {
        var checkedStatus = $(this).is(':checked');
        if (checkedStatus) {
            $('.citycheck li input[type="checkbox"]').not($(this).parent(".citycheck").find(".k-group .k-item input:checkbox[name=citycheck]")).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        }
        else {
            $(this).closest(".k-item").find(".k-group .k-item input:checkbox[name=citycheck]").each(function () {

                $(this).prop('checked', false);
                $("#Countries ul li div span:nth-of-type(2) input[type='checkbox'][name=citycheck]").removeAttr('disabled');
            });
        }

    }
```

Comment: What you mean by `disabled`?

Comment: suppose the treeview contains 10 parent nodes and  i select 3rd parent node, then remaining parent nodes has to be in disable mode that means we need to append a property "Disable". if we want to select another node first we need to un-select the current selected node.